# Set css style only to first row of the table

Tags: html, css

How to access with CSS first row of the table with different `tr` class name.

```
<div id="right">
 <table>
 <tbody>
 <tr class="head">
 <td >Date</td><td>Info</td><td>More</td>
 </tr>
<tr><td>...</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

How to make this css

```
#right table tr:first-child td:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px; 
}
#right table tr:first-child td:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

to apply only to .head

Comment: why can't you just use `#right .head td:first-child {...}`

Answer (score 4):

```
#right .head td:first-child{
    border-top-left-radius: 10px; 
}
#right .head td:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take it further by doing.

```
#right tr:first-child td:first-child {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Selecting the first tr and then the first td.

Answer (score 0):

use pseudo class `:first-child` to get the first element.

Like:

```
#right .head td:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px; 
}
#right .head td:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#right table tr.head td:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px; 
}
#right table tr.head td:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```