# Javascript sort column disable arrow up on first row and arrow down on last row

Tags: javascript

This is simple question, but don't know how to achieve it.

I'm working with sort column using jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".up,.down,.top,.bottom").click(function(){
        var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
        if ($(this).is(".up")) {
            row.insertBefore(row.prev());
        } else if ($(this).is(".down")) {
            row.insertAfter(row.next());
        } else if ($(this).is(".top")) {
            //row.insertAfter($("table tr:first"));
            row.insertBefore($("table tr:first"));
        }else {
            row.insertAfter($("table tr:last"));
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
            <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
            <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
            <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Four</td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
            <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Five</td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
            <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now I need to :

1. Disable "Up" on the first row
2. Disable "Down" on the last row

This will be always disable first and last row even I move another row to first or last.

Comment: Do you want to "gray it out" (CSS) or "raise an error message when it's clicked" (i.e. check if it's the first/last row in JavaScript)?

Comment: Yes, gray it out and  disable by `pointer-events: none`

Comment: Hi, just gray it and disable the pointer event. But I don't know to put the condition.

Comment: Then there are 2 options: (1)  remove the class from the first row before moving the rows around then add it later, or (2) only move the content/td, not the whole row.

Comment: (or just use CSS to select the first/last row. Besides the answer there's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41545623/css-selector-for-first-row-in-a-table https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850033/set-css-style-only-to-first-row-of-the-table )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that ?  (simply CSS + get rowIndex value [in case of keyboard return])

```js
const tableTbody = document.querySelector('table tbody')
  ,   FirstUp    = tableTbody.querySelector('tr:first-of-type').rowIndex
  ,   LastDown   = tableTbody.querySelector('tr:last-of-type').rowIndex
  ;
tableTbody.onclick = e =>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('a[data-mv]')) return

  let rIndex = e.target.closest('tr').rowIndex

  switch (e.target.dataset.mv)
    {
    case 'up':
      if (rIndex != FirstUp)
        tableTbody.insertBefore(tableTbody.rows[rIndex], tableTbody.rows[rIndex-1])
      break
    case 'down':
      if (rIndex != LastDown)
        tableTbody.insertBefore(tableTbody.rows[rIndex+1], tableTbody.rows[rIndex])
      break
    }
  }
```

```css
#myTable tbody tr:first-of-type a[data-mv=up],
#myTable tbody tr:last-of-type  a[data-mv=down] {
  cursor          : not-allowed;
  pointer-events  : none;
  opacity         : 0.5;
  text-decoration : none;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td> <a href="#" data-mv="up">Up</a> <a href="#" data-mv="down">Down</a> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td> <a href="#" data-mv="up">Up</a> <a href="#" data-mv="down">Down</a> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td> <a href="#" data-mv="up">Up</a> <a href="#" data-mv="down">Down</a> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Four</td>
      <td> <a href="#" data-mv="up">Up</a> <a href="#" data-mv="down">Down</a> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Five</td>
      <td> <a href="#" data-mv="up">Up</a> <a href="#" data-mv="down">Down</a> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```